# How to cut the portion and highlight it

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mask

Suppose we take any image from Internet and then copy or move some part from that image to any other area inside that image  the image should show from where that the part is copied / moved and then pasted. By using matlab.

```
a = imread('obama.jpg');
a = rgb2gray(a);
[x1 y1] = size(a);
b = uint8(imcrop(a, [170 110 200 150]));
[x2 y2] = size(b);
c = uint8(zeros(x1,y1));
for i = 1:x2
    for j = 1:y2
            c(i+169,j+109) = b(i,j);
    end
end
[x3 y3] = size(c)
subplot(1,3,1),imshow(a);
subplot(1,3,2),imshow(b);
subplot(1,3,3),imshow(c);
```

Comment: Also getting the size of c > size of a why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Input data and params
a = imread('Lenna.png');
a = rgb2gray(a);

src_xy = [300,300]; %% Starting X-Y of the source from where the portion would be cut from
src_dims = [100 100]; %% Dimensions of the portion to be cut
tgt_xy = [200,200]; %%  Starting X-Y of the target to where the portion would be put into

%%// Get masks
msrc = false(size(a));
msrc(src_xy(1):src_xy(1)+src_dims(1)-1,src_xy(2):src_xy(2)+src_dims(2)-1)=true;

mtgt = false(size(a));
mtgt(tgt_xy(1):tgt_xy(1)+src_dims(1)-1,tgt_xy(2):tgt_xy(2)+src_dims(2)-1)=true;

%%// If you would like to have a cursor based cut, explore ROIPOLY, GINPUT - e.g. - mask1 = roipoly(a)
mask1 = msrc;
a2 = double(a);

%%// Get crop-mask boundary and dilate it a bit to show it as the "frame" on the original image
a2(imdilate(edge(mask1,'sobel'),strel('disk',2))) = 0;
a2 = uint8(a2);

%%// Display original image with cropped portion being highlighted
figure,imshow(a2);title('Cropped portion highlighted')

figure,imshow(a);title('Original Image')

figure,imshow(mask1);title('Mask that was cropped')

img1 = uint8(bsxfun(@times,double(a),mask1));
figure,imshow(img1);title('Masked portion of image')

%%// Get and display original image with cropped portion being overlayed at the target coordinates
a_final = a;
a_final(mtgt) = a(msrc);
figure,imshow(uint8(a_final));title('Original image with the cut portion being overlayed')
```

**Output**

[image]

Please note that to use RGB images, you would need to tinker a bit more with the above code.

Comment: No sir i want to make use of marker to point out specific portion for example to point out the left eye of the women in your photo.

Comment: I am very happy with your answer mr Divakar but i also need- in an image how to copy and move some part in matlab for example in your image the highlighted area should move somewhere within the image.

Comment: How would you define "somewhere"? Computers don't understand "somewhere".

Comment: let one small portion be (20*20) be the higligted area which we want to move at the location with start co-ordinate as (200,200) and the original image is of size(1024,1024)

Comment: Edited for those changes. Please try to tinker around with the Input Data and Param values. Also, please try to work with `ginput` and `roipoly` to use cursor based selections!